# Passing variables into Python

Tags: python, variables

I would like to replace the strings in the following codeline with variables

```
myText = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x02''(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)
```

it should like this then

```
myText = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x02''(.*?)' & variable_XY &, s)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This question isn't very clear. What are you intending with the double apostrophe in the middle of the byte string? What is the `& variable_XY &` supposed to be doing? Is `&` just supposed to concatenate, or something else? And if the former, why is there another `&` at the end?

Comment: It seems like you're missing at least one key piece of information: `b'foo'` is a byte string. The b is part of the "quotes" around the byte string, not a separate operator or something. Meanwhile, if there's a language you know better, maybe you can write the JavaScript or PHP or whatever equivalent of what you're trying to do, and someone can show you how to translate it to Python?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
variable_XY = b'\xF7\x00\xF0'
myText = re.findall(b'\x03\x00\x00\x02(.*?)' + variable_XY, s)
```

Obviously `variable_XY` can be set in any way, as long as it is a string.

Comment: The literal `b'\x03\x00\x00\x02''(.*?)'` consists of a `bytes` literal `b'\x03\x00\x00\x02'` and a `str` literal `'(.*?)'` which are implicitly concatenated.  In Python 2.x this is valid, but pointless.  In Python 3.x, this is a syntax error.

Comment: Also, it might be worth telling him about string formatting (or the old-style `%s` formatting) instead of concatenation, because I suspect he's soon going to want to know "OK, but how do I replace something in the middle instead of at the end"?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I copy/pasted from the OP, and didn't spot it. Let me fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! At this position it works fine. But what if I want to pass the variable at this position:

myText = re.findall( b + variable_XY + '(.*?)''\xF7\x00\xF0', s)

I did not work with the concatenation at this position.

Comment: It's a good idea to always `re.escape` strings used to build REs.

Comment: Wow, I'm psychic. fernandes, you can't separate the `b` prefix from the string. To add variable_XY at the start, you can do `variable_XY + b'(.*?)`…. To add it in the middle, `b'(.*?)' + variable_XY + `b'blahblah'`. And so on. But again, formatting/%-formatting is probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's just concatenation.

If you want the contents of `variable_XY` at the end:

```
myText = re.findall( b'\x03\x00\x00\x02(.*?)' + variable_XY, s)
```

If you want the contents of `variable_XY` at the start:

```
myText = re.findall( variable_XY + b'\x03\x00\x00\x02(.*?)', s)
```